# json object is not returning but info service method is called , I can view the response object at inspect element (network section)

Tags: json, spring, rest, gwt

Service method:

```
@POST
@Path("/loaduser")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getinfo(employeedatapojo emp, MethodCallback < employeedatapojo > methodCallback);



//doa

@RequestMapping(value = "/loaduser", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public @ResponseBody employeedatapojo getinfo(@RequestBody employeedatapojo emp, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {


 boolean status = false;
 employeedatapojo empobj = new employeedatapojo();

 emplyoeedao obj1 = new emplyoeedao();
 empobj = obj1.returnempobject(emp.getemployeeid());
 System.out.println("languages inside loaduse restgwt" + empobj.getlanguages());

 return empobj;


}

//AT the ui side
//load user is executing but response is not coming

InfoService.Util.getService().loaduser(emp1, new MethodCallback < employeedatapojo > () {

   @Override
   public void onSuccess(Method method, employeedatapojo response) {
    Window.alert("inside user info after receiving object");

   }
   @Override
   public void onFailure(Method method, Throwable exception) {

    Window.alert("not assigned ");

   }
```